# Getting specific image sizes from asset_url

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to take advantage of the image size parameter, but it seems to not work on assets stored in my assets folders?
The following:

```
<img src="{{"image.png" | asset_url : '100x100'}}">
```

Throws this error:

> Liquid error: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)

Do I have to manually resize these assets?
The above works just fine without the '100x100', loads the image and whatnot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use **asset_img_url** filter instead of **asset_url**. Doing so, your code should become

```
<img src="{{'image.png' | asset_img_url : '100x100'}}">
```

Shopify Docs for [Asset Image Filter](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/filters/url-filters#asset_img_url)